# Why do we not see snow or much of season change in the Walking Dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

I do not recall seeing much snow or any serious weather change in the Walking Dead series. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: note that Atlanta -- where the show was set until recently -- almost never gets snow in real life either.

Answer (score 9):

> Recently, The Walking Dead executive producer Gale Anne Hurd was asked
>   about the frequent lack of changes in the weather on the series by
>   Access Hollywood, and let the outlet in on a little secret; the lack
>   of seasons totally has to do with the drama’s production schedule.
>
> "Yeah, it's dependent on the weather when we shoot."
>
> It’s not likely we’ll get to see a winter wonderland on the show
>   anytime soon, although Hurd also tells Access Hollywood that she would
>   love to see snow in the cards should the show be able to finagle it.
>
> "We do shoot right up until Thanksgiving, so if there is an early
>   snowfall in Georgia, we'll be happy to capture it."

Taken verbatim from [this website](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/Why-We-Rarely-See-Weather-Seasons-Walking-Dead-69934.html)

Comment: Would be interesting to hear how a canon answer got downvoted.

Comment: Note that S6E9 was shot during summer. On Talking Dead after that episode, Greg Nicotero (who was a guest on the show, and directed that episode) specifically stated that the greatest difficulty was not the various pyrotechnic effects, but filming them along with everything else (multiple shoots, some of which took hours) in such a way that the episode progressed from dusk until dawn in a continuous manner *given that* the summer in Georgia only gave about six hours of pitch black night to shoot. Being the midseason after the break episode, this corroborates Gale's quote above.

Comment: "frequent lack of changes"?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's mainly because winter is more of a danger to the cast. Ice can form on the ground and cause some people to slip and put themselves at risk of serious injuries not to mention it's easy to fall ill in those weather conditions meaning a cast member gets sick they have to postpone shooting until that member recovers fully and then everything gets set back.